# Define constants needed in more than one class

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

In my smart client solution, I have a Project folder with:

```
IProjectView.cs 
*ProjectView*  
     ProjectView.cs  
        ProjectView.Designer.cs  
     ProjectView.GeneratedCode.cs  
     ProjectView.resx  
     ProjectViewPresenter.cs
```

I want to define some constants for user by ProjectView.cs and ProjectViewPresenter.cs. Both of these classes implement IProjectView.cs, so were I back in Java, I'd put them there. If this were C++, I'd create a class ProjectConstants.cs and have the classes inherit it, but C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

How do I do this?

Comment: You don't need to inherit from a class to access constants in it, in *any* of those languages.  It doesn't even make sense to use inheritance to provide access to constants.

Comment: `ProjectView.cs` and `ProjectViewPresenter.cs` would be the only ones to use those constants?

Comment: @Servy: So you are suggesting to declare the constants public static in a class and access them that way?

Comment: @dcg: At this point, yes.

Comment: @AlLelopath You misspelled Servy, so he's not going to get notified that you responded to him.

Comment: thanks, corrected.

Comment: @AlLelopath If you declare the `static` then they're not constants...only variables can be marked as `static`.

Comment: @AlLelopath, you could create an `abstract` class that implements the interface `IProjectView` and there create those constants `protected`. But any inheritor would have them and not only `ProjectView` and `ProjectViewPresenter`.

Comment: Are you looking for "only 2 classes" case or just sharing constants? (Later looks like the goal of this question in current state and is completely opinion based as coding style as such)

Comment: @Servy, You are correct that it doesn't make sense to use inheritance to access constants, but I'm trying to work with the language. You are also correct in that I didn't mean `static`, but rather `public const string MY_STRING = "String";` I guess that's what I'll do. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you going to use as constants? `const` in appropriate class is the right place to store constant. Something can be represented with `enum`, something with static `readonly` field or getter-only property belonging to certain type. There is no need to hold **everything** in one place. But as you are not giving an example of *constant* it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can having a Read-Only Property in your interface solve your problem?

```
string MyReadOnlyProperty { get; }
```

I have no clue if this is very performance-wise compared to constant thought.

Comment: That technically would work. It seems like more than is necessary and, like you, I don't know about the performance issue.